# jQuery UI Datepicker - prevent refresh on date click

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

I changed year dropdown in Datepicker to textbox, because I want manual input for year.
But when I select some day, textbox returns to dropdown. How can I prevent that?

This is my [fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/nemanjas90/Fa8Xx/3610/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="datepicker"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function() {  
        $(this).data('datepicker').inline = true;      
        var curDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');        
        var month = $(".ui-datepicker-month").val();
        var year = $(".ui-datepicker-month").next("input").val();
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, $.datepicker.formatDate('dd', curDate)));

                //var text = $("<input type='text'id = 'textbox' style='width:106px' value='2015'/>");
    //$(".ui-datepicker-year").before(text).hide();
    }        
});
var text = $("<input type='text'id = 'textbox' style='width:106px' value='2015'/>");
$(".ui-datepicker-year").before(text).hide();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets here.

Comment: Where the page refreshing ?

Comment: On date click in Datepicker, some refreshing or update happens, I found that is datepicker_Update method and I can't prevent that...This method backs year to dropdown. Scenario: change year to 20xx, and click on any day, year field will become dropdown list.

Comment: If someone knows...?

Answer (score 1):

The option `onSelect` does some code execution after selecting date.

See the line `$("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, $.datepicker.formatDate('dd', curDate)));` inside `onSelect` block.

there you are again assigning today's date . so just remove or comment it .

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nawrddo5/)